# Multiproccessed chromedrivers causes the build of my tkinter programme to open extra tkinter windows

Tags: tkinter, multiprocessing, selenium-chromedriver, cx-freeze, python-idle

I have a very basic tkinter programme (basically i want to be able to run a few detatched multiproccesed chromedrivers at the click of a button.) it all works fine in idle, but when i use cx_freeze to make a build it behaves differently.

When i click go on the build version, it opens a brand new tkinter window and also runs the chromedriver functions. this also happens when i run the programme in cmd line instead of idle. but in idle its all fine, it simply runs the functions without opening a new window.

Script

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.options as Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process

def open_a_page(): # open one chromedriver in detatched mode (because i specifically want it to stay open when finished)
    driver_xpath2 = "chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = Options.Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_xpath2 ,options=chrome_options )
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print("yo   ")
    time.sleep(2)

def open_2_pages():
    processes = []
    for i in range(2):
        p1 = Process( target = open_a_page , args = ())
        processes.append(p1)
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()    
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    print("done    ")

window=Tk()     
B = Button(window, text ="go", command = open_2_pages)  # when i click this button it opens 2 googles
B.place(x=10, y=10);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop();
```

I want my build / command line, to work just like it does in idle. What have i done wrong here?

#### UPDATE

I tried to simplify the problem further by removing chrome driver from the equation, however this fixed the problem. so i think chromedriver is to blame.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process

def dothing(): # do a thing
    print("yo   ")


def open_2_things():
    processes = []
    for i in range(2):
        p1 = Process( target = dothing , args = ())
        processes.append(p1)
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()    
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    print("done    ")

window=Tk()     
B = Button(window, text ="go", command = open_2_things)  # when i click this button it do 2 things
B.place(x=10, y=10);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop();
```

How can i make my original program work with multiproccesed detatched chromedrivers without it opening additional tkinter windows?

#### update 2

I have removed the multiproccesing, but left in the chromedriver, this also fixes the problem.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.options as Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from tkinter import *


def open_a_page(): # open one chromedriver in detatched mode (because i specifically want it to stay open when finished)
    driver_xpath2 = "chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_options = Options.Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_xpath2 ,options=chrome_options )
    driver.get("https://www.google.com")
    print("yo   ")
    time.sleep(2)

def open_2_pages():
    processes = []
    for i in range(2):
        open_a_page()
        


window=Tk()     
B = Button(window, text ="go", command = open_2_pages)  # when i click this button it opens 2 googles
B.place(x=10, y=10);


window.mainloop();
```

So the problem is the combination of both multiprocessing and chromedriver, but individually they're fine.

How can i use multiprocessed chromedrivers with tkinter without it opening new windows? why does this happen?
why does everything work as intended running in pythons idle?

Comment: Can you please share your cx_Freeze setup script? And on which operating system?

Comment: I had a similar issue with multiprocessing.  You can see my answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/73228834/13258121