# build of multiproccesed tkinter programme opens new windows , but idle doesn't

Tags: python, tkinter, build, multiprocessing, cx-freeze

I have this programme that works as intended in idle. however my build with cx_freeze opens new windows each time i click go.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process

def dothing(): 
    print("yo   ")
    time.sleep(2)

def do_2_things():
    processes = []
    for i in range(2):
        p1 = Process( target = dothing , args = ())
        processes.append(p1)
    for proc in processes:
        proc.start()    
    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
    print("done    ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window=Tk()     
    B = Button(window, text ="go", command = do_2_things)  
    B.place(x=10, y=10);
    window.mainloop();
```

Why does running it in idle behave differently from my build? how can I get it to stop opening new windows? ive been asking around with this problem for a while, please help.

Comment: if you get multiple windows that means that whatever cx_Freeze does makes it mess with `__name__`, i'm not familiar with it specifically so i am unable to guide you further

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiproccessed chromedrivers causes the build of my tkinter programme to open extra tkinter windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966294/multiproccessed-chromedrivers-causes-the-build-of-my-tkinter-programme-to-open-e)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.