# My multithread tkinter code only works when I run it on Pycharm, not in an .exe. It opens an unwanted window, even with __name__ == "__main__"

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have multiple files in this project, and, in this particular case, I call a function from another file.

```
from botmain import Execute

def EXECUTE_BOT(first_line, last_line, filename, padrao_comunicacao, concentrador, varredura, eventos, osci, param, ons,
                empresa, grpparam, cnldgt, addparams):
    time.sleep(5)
    Execute(first_line,
            last_line,
            filename,
            padrao_comunicacao,
            concentrador,
            varredura,
            eventos,
            osci,
            param,
            ons,
            empresa,
            grpparam,
            cnldgt,
            addparams)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.grab_set()
    root.resizable = False
    frm = ttk.Frame(root, padding=20)
    frm.grid()

    ttk.Button(frm, text="EXECUTAR", command=lambda: EXECUTE_BOT(wdg_firstLine.get(),
                                                                 wdg_lastLine.get(),
                                                                 wdg_sheetdirectory.cget("text"),
                                                                 wdg_padrao_comunicacao.get(),
                                                                 wdg_conc.get(),
                                                                 radio_var.get(),
                                                                 radio_eve.get(),
                                                                 radio_osc.get(),
                                                                 radio_param.get(),
                                                                 radio_ons.get(),
                                                                 wdg_empresa.get(),
                                                                 wdg_grpParam.get(),
                                                                 wdg_cnlDgt.get(),
                                                                 converAddParam(addparam_list))).grid(column=5, row=22)
```

This code works just fine when I run it on Pycharm, but when I make it a .exe with pyinstaller, it stops working, and it opens another window every time I click on that button. I fixed this error by putting my code inside **name** == "**main**", but when I make it an .exe, it gets the same error than when I didn't have that.

Heeeeelp!!!

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @Matiiss It opens another window, there's no error code or anything like that

Comment: there has to be an error, run the executable from `cmd`, i.e. `path/to/whatever>your_exe.exe` and see if any errors pop up in the console there

Comment: @Matiiss there is not, i already ran from cmd

Comment: Your code should not show any window when running in console because `mainloop()` is missing.  Also `tkinter` module is not imported as well.

Comment: @acw1668 it is imported, I just didn't include it in the post because I thought it would be implicit. And that's how it works about `mainloop()`, dude, i've already tested it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, but when my multithread function was called it created a new `root` for each process.  `multiprocessing` `freeze_support()` was the answer, read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support)

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support() # to stop exe popups when threaded
```